# sed command replace text with ' character

Tags: sed

I have an very big sql file that I cant open in a gui editor. I need to replace the string 
'user1'@'localhost' (note the ` character) by 'user2'@'localhost'  but i am having troubles finding the right syntax for sed command.

I can get the strings to replace correcly using the following grep command:

```
grep -w 'user1`@`localhost'
```

Any help please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought of a more general solution than as your question asks for.

Let's imagine you need to find a string based on your regular expression search criteria. You'd like to replace only a part of it, and leave the other matching parts unchanged.

To demonstrate with an example:

```
echo "'some-name'@'some-host'" | sed -r "s/(')([^']+)('@'[^']*')/\1user2\3/g"
```

will display:

```
'user2'@'some-host'
```

The `sed` command performs the replacement by using the `s/search-regexp/replacement/g` syntax. In our case:

- `(')` matches the first single quote. This is trivial, but could be more complex. It represents the part of the string before the replacement. `sed` assigns the value of this sub-expression to the special variable `\1`.
- `([^']+)` matches the user name. Basically any character starting from the previous position that is not a quote. `sed` assigns the value of this sub-expression to the special variable `\2`.
- `('@'[^']*')` matches the `'@'host-name'` part. Similarly to the previous sub-expression, a quote, a `@`, a quote again and any character that is not a quote and then a quote at the end. `sed` assigns the value of this sub-expression to the special variable `\3`.

The replacement part will replace anything that matched the search-regexp. By using the variables shown above, we can replace the user name and leave the other regions intact. `\1` + *your new user name* + `\3` will produce the desired result. Thus:

```
\1user2\3
```

Results in:

- Whatever contents the first sub-expression has, (it is a single quote)
- followed by the string "user2", (note `\2` is intentionally not used, because we replace the user name)
- and finally the contents of the 3rd sub-expression (which is a `'@` and the host name in quotes).

If you `cat` your script file and pipe it to the `sed` command, you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your sed command around speechmarks will work:

```
adder@adamj-T1500:~$ cat sed_test 
user1'@'localhost
adder@adamj-T1500:~$ sed -i -e "s/user1'@'localhost/user2'@'localhost/" sed_test
adder@adamj-T1500:~$ cat sed_test 
user2'@'localhost
```

There's a number of different ways you can escape a single quote for a `sed` command, there's a number of questions with answers on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112157/escaping-single-quotes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990750/escape-single-quote

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517632/how-do-i-escape-double-and-single-quotes-in-sed-bash